# What does "touch /reconfigure" before a reboot do?

Tags: linux, shutdown, init, touch

We have a situation that spontaneous shutdowns are occurring on our Wind River Linux 6 system, and in the syslog, I see a `/bin/touch /reconfigure` followed by an `/sbin/init 0`. I can tell from another Unix StackExchange question that this a "reconfiguration reboot" but I can't determine from SE or Google what exactly this means or does under Linux, or more important why it is being issued or what might be issuing it.

Comment: That looks like a Solaris habit (e.g. [one particular google hit](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/805-6331/6j5vgg6aa/index.html))

Comment: That's a help. I've been ignoring the Solaris hits because we're not running Solaris but it hadn't occurred to me that it might be a legacy behavior. Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible that you have some "automation" that's doing it "for" (to) you?

Comment: Oh I definitely think so. I was on a session when it happened and no shutdown wall message was issued. Something's gone rogue and I'm trying to figure out what it is.

Comment: As-is, this questions asks "what does `touch /reconfigure` do?" -- do you want to leave that as the focus of this question, on Linux, or adjust it to change the behavior upstream?

Comment: I asked the "automation" question because if it's a human sysadmin doing it, you could go ask them what they were intending, and how long they had been a Solaris admin :)  If it's some software doing it, it's possible that it has misunderstood your system as being a Solaris one.

Comment: If I understand your question, for now, I'll leave it because I think your answer implicates our software so it's not useful to ask here. If I get to the point where I want to ask the question "how do I find out what's issuing this shutdown command" I'll do that in a separate question if necessary. I may not end up being the one finishing the investigation, anyway. Thanks for your help!

Comment: `touch /reconfigure`, like `touch /forcefsck` makes use of the filesystem to set a flag that will be seen by the startup scripts of the next boot. `grep /reconfigure /etc/init*/*` to find where it's used.

Comment: I did do that (actually I did a find) and nothing came up. And the file is still there after boot; I'd think if it was a flag it'd get deleted after use.